# Use strcpy() or strncpy() for array of strings?

Tags: c, arrays, string, strcpy, strncpy

I'm struggling to copy a string within an array at a given index to another array of strings, any suggestions? When trying to print out the value of tempVal at any given index, it doesn't return anything.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {

   const int NUM_VALS = 20;
   int i;
   int matchCount = 0;

   int actualInput;
   scanf("%d", &actualInput);
   char userString[actualInput][NUM_VALS];
   char tempVal[actualInput][NUM_VALS];

   for (i = 0; i < actualInput; ++i) {
      scanf("%s", userString[i]);
      // printf("%s", userString[i]);
         strncpy(userString[i], tempVal[i], strlen(userString[i])); // < -- Not sure how to make work
         printf("%s", tempVal[i]); // <-- Doesn't output anything?
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: There is almost never a good reason to use [`strncpy`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strncpy/) read the documentation carefulley. Especially the parte that says: _No null-character is implicitly appended at the end of destination if source is longer than num. Thus, in this case, destination shall not be considered a null terminated C string (reading it as such would overflow)._

Comment: [How can code that tries to prevent a buffer overflow end up causing one?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050107-00/?p=36773)

Answer (score 0):

use the function which will limit the number of chars read and place the terminatins zero as well

```
for (int i = 0; i < actualInput; ++i) {
    fgets(userString[i], NUM_VALS, stdin);
    strcpy(tempVal[i], userString[i]); // < -- Not sure how to make work
    printf("%s\n", tempVal[i]); // <-- Doesn't output anything?
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is no wonder why you got no appropriate output because with the provided code you high-probably will get a Segmentation fault. Beside this, there are several issues in the code. To explain them all and also answer the heading question would explode the frame. You can see how I corrected the code in my manner below.

> char* strcpy ( char* destination, const char* source )

`strcpy` is a potential risk for causing buffer overflow if the `destination` `char` buffer is not large enough to hold the string to be copied by `source`. This in your case okay, because each buffers, `userString[i]` and `tempVal[i]`, have the same capacity (amount of `char` elements), but if the code changes it could be harmful.

Note that you also should limit the amount of input characters when you catch the string from `stdin`. For this reason, `fgets()` is safer than `scanf()`, since it explicitly requires a maximum amount of characters to read.

> char* strncpy ( char* destination, const char* source, size_t num );

`strncpy` fails to append a terminating null character if the first `num` characters of the source string do not contain a terminating `\0`.

Rather use `snprintf()` which is safe to 1. proofs the size of the destination buffer and limits the amount of characters to read and 2. always appends a null character (assuming the scan process was successful and no errors occurred):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {

   const int NUM_VALS = 20;
   int i;

   int s_num;
   printf("Enter number of strings in array: ");
   scanf("%d", &s_num);
   getchar();

   char userString[s_num][NUM_VALS];
   char tempVal[s_num][NUM_VALS];

   for (i = 0; i < s_num; ++i) {
   printf("Enter string at userString[%d]: ",i);

   if(fgets(userString[i],NUM_VALS, stdin) == NULL)
   {
       // error handling
       if(ferror(stdin))
       {
            // handle I/O error.
       }
       else if(feof(stdin))
       {
           // end of file is reached.
       }
   }
   else
       userString[i][strcspn(userString[i], "\n")] = 0;

   //printf("%s", userString[i]);
   }

   printf("\n");

   for (i = 0; i < s_num; ++i) {

      if(snprintf(tempVal[i], sizeof(tempVal[i]), "%s", userString[i]) < 0)
      {
        // error handling
        fprintf(stderr,"Encoding error occurred!");
      }
      printf("tempValue[%d]: %s\n", i, tempVal[i]);
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Output at a test run:

```
Enter number of strings in array: 3               
Enter string at userString[0]: hello    
Enter string at userString[1]: world 
Enter string at userString[2]: test

tempValue[0]: hello
tempValue[1]: world
tempValue[2]: test
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys,

I am taking a class and new to C. I was able to figure out how to solve my problem. I appreciate the suggestions for fixing the code, unfortunately they are beyond the scope of what I have learned in my intro course. I had to find word frequencies using a string array and for loops. Here is the complete working code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {

   const int NUM_VALS = 20;
   int i;
   int j;
   int matchCount = 0;

   int actualInput;
   scanf("%d", &actualInput);

   char userString[actualInput][NUM_VALS];
   char tempVal[actualInput][NUM_VALS];

   for (i = 0; i < actualInput; ++i) {
      scanf("%s", userString[i]);
      strcpy(tempVal[i], userString[i]);
     // printf("%s\n", userString[i]);
     // printf("%s\n", tempVal[i]);
   }

   for (i = 0; i < actualInput; ++i) {
      matchCount = 0;
      for (j = 0; j < actualInput; ++j) {
         if (strcmp(userString[i], tempVal[j]) == 0) {
            matchCount++;
         }
      }
      printf("%s %d\n", userString[i], matchCount);
   }



   return 0;
}
```